# Manager isn't accessible via object instances on object.save()

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following model definition in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

# this is the model for each user
class UTJUser(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(default=None)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_submission = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

I have the following signup function definition in views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
# for development purpose exempt csrf protection
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from users.models import UTJUser


# sign up function, use csrf exempt for development
@csrf_exempt
async def sign_up(request):
    try:
        full_name, email, password = request.POST['full_name'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password']
        new_user = UTJUser(full_name=full_name,email=email,password=password)
        await new_user.save()
        return HttpResponse("Sign up success!")
    except:
        return HttpResponse.status_code
```

However, when I run the line

```
new_user = UTJUser(full_name=full_name,email=email,password=password)
```

an error occur in the objects attribute of new_user:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\\Users\\micha\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\\pythonFiles\\lib\\python\\debugpy\\_vendored\\pydevd\\_pydevd_bundle\\pydevd_resolver.py", line 189, in _get_py_dictionary
    attr = getattr(var, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\\Users\\micha\\Documents\\UTJ\\backend\\UTJEnv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\manager.py", line 186, in __get__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Manager isn\'t accessible via UTJUser instances
```

And the final error that is returned is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\micha\Documents\UTJ\backend\UTJEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\micha\Documents\UTJ\backend\UTJEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\micha\Documents\UTJ\backend\UTJEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What is the problem? I am new to Django, and I thought I was just following the basics of storing objects in PostgreSQL database as in this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/

I am using django v5.0.1 and psycopg2 v2.2.9

**EDIT:**

The second error was a misuse in HttpResponse in the Exception handler. But the first error still persist, even after removing await

Comment: `await new_user.asave()`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem That's definitely an issue, but I would expect it to cause a `SynchronousOnlyOperation`, not the traceback in the question.

Comment: The second error is because you return `return HttpResponse.status_code`, which is an `int` (200) and not a `HttpResponse` object. Change it to something like `return HttpResponseServerError()`.

Comment: @Selcuk: yes, the "outer" one is, the inner is due to the `await` I think, because that calls the function, but it is of course not what `await` is expecting.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem The second error is resolved with HttpResponseServerError(). But the first error occurred in the line before new_user.save() (I removed await and there is still an error)...In debug mode, I can see the error in the new_user attribute "objects" right after the User object is created. But the except code only got triggered when new_user.save() is called

Comment: @MichaelMo You shouldn't remove the `await`, you should change `.save()` to `.asave()` (asynchronous save).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved with using new_user.asave().